# Mutual friends sql with join (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

users table:

```
id|name
```

user_relationships

```
id | user_id | friend_id
```

and want to get names of mutual friends of 2 users. i.e:

```
user_relationships
1 | 1 | 3
2 | 2 | 3  

users
3| sammy
```

users 1 and 2 have mutual friend 3. I want to get his name 'sammy' in one query.

How do I do that?

Comment: You want to get only the name or `1 | 1 | 3 | sammy`?

Comment: listing all mutual friends for all users with user names? or listing people which are mutual firend of any other users and you do not care the names? or you already have user1 and user2 and you want the mutual friends names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name
FROM users
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT friend_id
  FROM user_relationships
  WHERE user_id IN ( 1, 2 )
  GROUP BY friend_id
  HAVING COUNT(friend_id) >= 2
)
```

or with one join:

```
SELECT friend_id, name
FROM user_relationships r
  INNER JOIN users u ON r.friend_id = u.id
WHERE user_id IN ( 1, 2 )
GROUP BY friend_id
HAVING COUNT(friend_id) >= 2
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to join user_relationships with itself, so that two rows with different `user_id` have the same `friend_id`

All mutual friends:

```
select ur1.user_id user1, 
       ur2.user_id user2, 
       ur2.friend_id mutual_friend
from   user_relationships ur1 
       JOIN user_relationships ur2 ON  ur1.friend_id = ur2.friend_id
where  ur1.user_id != ur2.user_id
```

Join with users table to get the names:

```
select ur1.user_id user_id1, 
        u1.name User1, 
       ur2.user_id user2, 
        u2.name User2,
       ur2.friend_id mutual_friend_id,
        u3.name mutual_friend
from user_relationships ur1 
     JOIN user_relationships ur2 ON  ur1.friend_id = ur2.friend_id
     JOIN user u1 ON u1.user_id = ur1.user_id
     JOIN user u2 ON u1.user_id = ur2.user_id
     JOIN user u3 ON ur1.user_id = u3.user_id
where ur1.user_id != ur2.user_id
```

You can filter for mutual friends for some specific users using `ur1.user_id = first_user` and `ur2.user_id = second_user`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
select id, name from users where id in 
    (select friend_id from user_relationships where user_id = @user1_id and friend_id in 
        (select friend_id from user_relationships where user_id = @user2_id)
    )
```

This should return all mutual friends of users with the IDs @user1_id and @user2_id. 
It's not tested yet, but should provide a starting point...

Answer (score 0):

didn't check it but this query should give you a list of related user names for ID [no].

```
select u1.name, u2.name 
  from users as u1
  join user_relationships as ur
    on u1.id = ur.user_id
  join users as u2
    on ur.friend_id = u2.id
  where U1.id = [no];
```

BTW, you don't need an artificial id for your cross-table, as (user_id, friend_id) is already a legitimate primary key.