# How to select mutual friends

Tags: php, mysql

please i want to select mutual friends of a user and the `$my_id` is the `$_SESSION['user'];` 
while the `$user_id` is the selected user. here is the code:

```
    <?php

include 'connect.php';

include 'functions.php';

$my_frnds = mysqli_query{$con, "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE one='$my_id' OR two='$my_id'"};
while($my_friends = mysqli_fetch_array($my_frnds)){
    $one = $my_friends['one'];
    $two = $my_friends['two'];

    if($one == $my_id){
        $user == $two;
    } else
        $user == $one;
}

$user_frnds = mysqli_query{$con, "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE one='$user_id' OR two='$user_id'"};
while($user_friends = mysqli_fetch_array($user_frnds)){
    $user_one = $user_friends['one'];
    $user_two = $user_friends['two'];

    if($user_one == $my_id){
        $users == $user_two;
    } else
        $users == $user_one;
}

?>
```

lets assume that my friends are (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) and the user friends are (2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) so the mutual friends are (2, 4, 6, 7) my question is how do i get the mutual friend out and echo thier ids?. Sorry i made a mistake, here is the original coding

Comment: what is structure of table?

Comment: how you save the user friends, is **one** is your id and **two** is friend id?

Comment: sorry friends, i have edited the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mutual friends sql with join (Mysql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731514/mutual-friends-sql-with-join-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

in case one is your id and two is friend id:

```
select * from friends 
inner join (select * from friends where one = $user_id) as temp on temp.two = friends.two
where friends.one = $my_id
```

Comment: @KingKanayoAustinLengend doesn't the above query solve your problem?

Comment: pardon me I am sincerely confused but i tried it , its not working perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM friends AS f1
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM friends WHERE one = $user_id OR two = $user_id) AS f2 
    ON (f1.one = f2.one OR f1.one = f2.two) 
    WHERE f1.one = $my_id OR f1.two = $my_id
```

hope this helps.

Comment: yes, the query for my friends is perfectly okay and same for the query for the user's friends