# Mutual friends sql

Tags: mysql

I've seen multiple SO posts on mutual friends but I've structured my friends table in my db so that there are no duplicates e.g. (1,2) and not (2,1)

```
    Create Table Friends(
      user1_id int, 
      user2_id int
    );
```

and then a constraint to make sure user1 id is always smaller than user2 id e.g 4 < 5

[Mutual friends sql with join (Mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731514/mutual-friends-sql-with-join-mysql)

I see suggestions that to find mutual friends it can be found using a join, so this is what I have but I think it's wrong because if I count the data in my db with the actual result from the query I get different results

```
select f1.user1_id as user1, f2.user1_id as user2, count(f1.user2_id) as 
mutual_count from Friends f1 JOIN Friends f2 ON 
f1.user2_id = f2.user2_id AND f1.user1_id <> f2.user1_id  GROUP BY
f1.user1_id, f2.user1_id order by mutual_count desc
```

Comment: I hope you've indexed that table properly. Additionally calling them `user1` and `user2` is a little vague. Why not `user_id` and `friend_of_id` to establish directionality?

Comment: yeah I could change the names

Comment: If 1 is friends with 2, and 2 is friends with 3, your query doesn't join them.  You're joining on `f1.user2_id = f2.user2_id`; you're treating `user2_id` as the mutual friend.  But you also have the constraint `user2_id > user1_id`.  You're query only accounts for friends of friends where the mutual friend has a higher id than Both other parties.  *(Same consequence when you have 1:2 and 1:3, those two records never get joined either.)*

Answer (score 0):

There are three join scenarios that I can see.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3    (mutual friend id between other IDs)    
2 -> 3 -> 1    (mutual friend id > other IDs)    
2 -> 1 -> 3    (mutual friend id < other IDs)
```

This *can* be resolved with this predicate...

```
ON f1.user1_id IN (f2.user1_id, f2.user2_id)
OR f1.user2_id IN (f2.user1_id, f2.user2_id)
AND <not joining the row to Itself>
```

But that will totally mess up the optimiser's ability to use indexes.

So, I'd union multiple queries.

*(pseudo code as I'm on a phone)*

```
SELECT u1, u2, COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT f1.u1, f2.u2 FROM f1 INNER JOIN f2 ON f1.u2 = f2.u1 AND f1.u1 <> f2.u2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT f1.u1, f2.u1 FROM f1 INNER JOIN f2 ON f1.u2 = f2.u2 AND f1.u1 <> f2.u1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT f1.u2, f2.u2 FROM f1 INNER JOIN f2 ON f1.u1 = f2.u1 AND f1.u2 <> f2.u2
) all_combinations
GROUP BY u1, u2
```

Each individual query will then be able to fully utilise indexes.  *(Put one index on `u1` and another index on `u2`)*

The result should be less esoteric code *(with fairly long CASE statements)* and a much lower costed execution plan.